# Errors with php-fpm sock

Tags: nginx, php

There is a big bad misconfiguration on my server , that I don't know where to go now.

My server Configuration is: NGINX + ionCube + igBinary + CLoudFlare (php-fpm)

Every time I try to start PHP-FPM I get stuck until I open a new session .

LOG says this :

> [02-May-2014 02:51:05] ERROR: An another FPM instance seems to already
>   listen on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
>
> [02-May-2014 02:51:05] ERROR: FPM initialization failed

and because of this I'm getting also :

> 2014/05/02 02:58:42 [error] 25729#0: *179211 upstream timed out (110:
>   Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 108...., server: thedomain.com, request: "POST
>   /contactengine.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "thedomain.com",
>   referrer: "http://thedomain.com/"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your FPM Pool configuration you'll find something like `[pool_name]` where `pool_name` is the name of your FPM Pool. There is also a socket file name listed later in that same configuration file.

There are 2 things which normally lead to this situation:

1) You have two FPM Pools named the same

2) You have two FPM Pools trying to start and use the same socket name

Check those configurations and make sure they are certainly different.

I typically name the configuration file the same name as the pool name and also the same name as the socket. This helps keeps things a bit more sane when troubleshooting problems like these.

It is fine that two domains / web configurations like Apache or Nginx use the same socket to connect to. The problem you have currently is in the FPM Pool configurations themselves.

Comment: Thanks @Diemuzi I search all the posible .conf with `find / -iname *.conf` ,  and nothing, I also separate every domain in a different poop calling different socket , and the same continue ....